# Is there a way to find an object in an application?

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework, pocketpc

Is there a way that I can parse through the objects of an application and determine if each one is TypeOf a particular form object? I have found no clear way getting a reference to forms that have already been opened. Complicating this further, it appears that not all Visual Basic commands are available to me when coding for an old PocketPC device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have alook into Reflection. With this you can get all types of a NameSpace, then get all members of all class then do your compare. Since Reflection is used for bindings it *might* be available in your framework.
So this could be a start :

```
    Dim MyAssembly = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
    Dim AllTypes = MyAssembly.GetTypes()
    Dim AllClass = From x In AllTypes Where x.IsClass Select x
```